# Android Drag and Drop, Click, and Scroll in a Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, ontouchlistener

So I have a layout as such: 
[image: Example of layout]

I am using a Listview right now and each row has an Imageview and 2 Textviews.

I want to be able to do 3 things on this page:

1. Clicking on a row (or just clicking on the Imageview in that row works for me too) brings me to another Fragment.
2. You can drag the image in each Listview row. It uses **DragShadowBuilder** and therefore can detect if you drop it into that darker gray zone in the bottom.
3. You can scroll up and down in the Listview to get to the other items that are overflowing right now.

As you can imagine, these three cases are difficult to capture because its hard to differentiate between the three (bc of overlaps in functionality).

I would prefer **not** to use onItemLongClickListener to do the drag and drop bc users usually don't think to hold their fingers down a long time to start drag and drop.

**Any suggestions on how to implement this to capture all three use cases?** Actually, it can be thought of as 2 use cases because if I dropped an image back into its original container, it could count as a click for me. The most complex part is to make that somehow work with scrolling up and down the Listview...

Thanks for your help in advance!

p.s. This entire view is rendered in a Fragment and clicking on a view or successfully dropping one into the gray area opens up a separate fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * Call this from a drag source view.
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (!mDragging) {
        return false;
    }

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final int screenX = clamp((int)ev.getRawX(), 0, mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels);
    final int screenY = clamp((int)ev.getRawY(), 0, mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels);

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // Remember where the motion event started
        mMotionDownX = screenX;
        mMotionDownY = screenY;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        //Set background color of remove comment box layout
        if(((int)ev.getY() <= 50))
            ImageEditingActivityNew.rl_remove.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        else
            ImageEditingActivityNew.rl_remove.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        // Update the drag view.  Don't use the clamped pos here so the dragging looks
        // like it goes off screen a little, intead of bumping up against the edge.
        mDragView.move((int)ev.getRawX(), (int)ev.getRawY());

        // Drop on someone?
        final int[] coordinates = mCoordinatesTemp;
        DropTarget dropTarget = findDropTarget(screenX, screenY, coordinates);
        if (dropTarget != null) {
            if (mLastDropTarget == dropTarget) {
                dropTarget.onDragOver(mDragSource, coordinates[0], coordinates[1],(int) mTouchOffsetX, (int) mTouchOffsetY, mDragView, mDragInfo);
            } else {
                if (mLastDropTarget != null) {
                    mLastDropTarget.onDragExit(mDragSource, coordinates[0], coordinates[1],(int) mTouchOffsetX, (int) mTouchOffsetY, mDragView, mDragInfo);
                }
                dropTarget.onDragEnter(mDragSource, coordinates[0], coordinates[1],
                    (int) mTouchOffsetX, (int) mTouchOffsetY, mDragView, mDragInfo);
            }
        } else {
            if (mLastDropTarget != null) {
                mLastDropTarget.onDragExit(mDragSource, coordinates[0], coordinates[1],
                    (int) mTouchOffsetX, (int) mTouchOffsetY, mDragView, mDragInfo);
            }
        }
        mLastDropTarget = dropTarget;


        /* The original Launcher activity supports a delete region and scrolling.
           It is not needed in this example.

        // Scroll, maybe, but not if we're in the delete region.
        boolean inDeleteRegion = false;
        if (mDeleteRegion != null) {
            inDeleteRegion = mDeleteRegion.contains(screenX, screenY);
        }
        //Log.d(TAG, "inDeleteRegion=" + inDeleteRegion + " screenX=" + screenX
        //        + " mScrollZone=" + mScrollZone);
        if (!inDeleteRegion && screenX < mScrollZone) {
            if (mScrollState == SCROLL_OUTSIDE_ZONE) {
                mScrollState = SCROLL_WAITING_IN_ZONE;
                mScrollRunnable.setDirection(SCROLL_LEFT);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mScrollRunnable, SCROLL_DELAY);
            }
        } else if (!inDeleteRegion && screenX > scrollView.getWidth() - mScrollZone) {
            if (mScrollState == SCROLL_OUTSIDE_ZONE) {
                mScrollState = SCROLL_WAITING_IN_ZONE;
                mScrollRunnable.setDirection(SCROLL_RIGHT);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mScrollRunnable, SCROLL_DELAY);
            }
        } else {
            if (mScrollState == SCROLL_WAITING_IN_ZONE) {
                mScrollState = SCROLL_OUTSIDE_ZONE;
                mScrollRunnable.setDirection(SCROLL_RIGHT);
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mScrollRunnable);
            }
        }
        */
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //When touch up then remove comment box

        if(((int)ev.getY() <= 50)) {
            ImageEditingActivity.rl_imageEdit_comment.removeAllViews();
            ImageEditingActivity.rl_imageEdit_comment.invalidate();
            //ImageEditingActivity.mDragLayer.removeView(ImageEditingActivity.rl_imageEdit_comment);
            ImageEditingActivity.addComment = true;
            ImageEditingActivity.changeIconBackground("Remove");
            ImageEditingActivity.editParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        }

        if (mDragging) {
            drop(screenX, screenY);
        }

        endDrag();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        cancelDrag();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hey Patel, this looks promising. Do you mind writing some explanation of what's going on in your code though? I'm not seeing the direct tie to what I was asking. Thanks!

Comment: You suppose to get maxY position of your screen and on move put condition your drag view is in maxY position then drop image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of long press and hold you can use fling/swipe gesture. You can override onFling method of [SimpleonGestureListner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) and detect fling based on the threshold.

Comment: The only problem I foresee though is managing the difference between onFling and onScroll. I want to be able to let the user scroll up and down the listview slowly/quickly. But I also want them to be drag the image in each listview row using DragShadowBuilder. Can I resolve that using SimpleOnGestureListener?

Comment: You have conflicting requirements but still you can give it a shot using dragshadow builder along with fling.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements conflicts. I would do the next thing in your case :

1. Your row can be drag only with long pressed (then I would use the shadow drag)
   also I would do that the view of the drop only appears when long press occurs.
2. `override` the `onclick` method of the `ImageView` that way you can click it and then call your fragment to expand
3. Now because you didn't override any `onTouchListeners` or `onClick` on the row you can scroll freely as long as you don't click a picture.